# Can you add multiple bits of information into one section of a database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make a database using SQL but I need to put multiple bits of data into one part of my database.
An example of this is that I have a column called 'car' and one called 'cars that park here' but multiple cars stop at one car park. How would I insert multiple cars into 'cars that park here'?

I'm relatively new to coding and still in school so any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: 1 Normal form [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) I suggest to use model it correctly with some kind of junction table between bus and busStop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a properly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database, you do not have multiple bits of information in a single column. In general, you solve this by moving the values into separate rows of another table:

```
table Stops:          table StopBuses:

StopID BusStopName    StopID Bus
------ -----------    ------ -----
    1  Victoria           1  BusA
                          1  BusB
                          1  BusX
```

(If your database has information about buses in another table, the `Bus` column would probably be an ID, too. This is the typical way of implementing a many-to-many relation between stops and buses.)